# Снова об этимологии

Tags: этимология

Я сегодня всех достал вопросами по этимологии)) Теперь меня интересуют слова "церковь" и "храм". Каково их происхождение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Церковь.** Происходит от зап.-герм. *kirika из др.-греч. (предположительно). Источником герм. слов является греч. κυρικόν из κυριακόν. Исторически более оправданная др.-в.-нем. этимология сопряжена с бо́льшими фонетическими трудностями, чем объяснение из готск. Неприемлема этимология из др.-сакс. kirikа или др.-сканд.* kirka. Точно так же неприемлемо толкование как заимств. через народнолат. *суriса или непосредственно из греч. κυρικόν. Отсюда: др.-русск. цьркы (род. п. -ъве), ст.-слав. црькы (др.-греч. ἐκκλησία, ναός), русск. церковь (народн. це́рква), укр. це́рква, белор. це́рква, болг. цръ́ква, че́рква, сербохорв. цр̑ква, словенск. cèrkǝv, польск. cerkiew, н.-луж. сеrkеj, полабск. саrḱоi, саrḱеv. Отличный хронологический слой представляют чешск.-церк.-слав. циръкы (род. п. -ъве; Киевск. листки, Рs. Sin.), др.-словенск. circuvah, местн. мн. (Фрейзинг. отрывки), чешск. církev, в.-луж. суrkеj. Источник предполагают в готск.-арианск.* kirikô «церковь» или в др.-бав. kirkô — стадия, предшествующая др.-в.-нем. chirihha.Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

---

**Храм.** Происходит от церк.-слав., ст.-слав. храмъ, при исконнорусск. хоромъ (см. хоро́мы). Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.